# Finish thread inside of it

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm developing a motion detection app, where I have a Thread that compares continously the screen frames for if there is movement, and if it is, it takes a capture and saves it.

Now I need to modify this, I need to do it just one time. After detecting movement, I need to start another method which will process some actions, but I no longer need the motionDetection thread, and due to some issues with it while I execute the new method, I would need to stop it and get out of it.

So, what would be the correct way to finish the thread when I start this new method?

Comment: how does it run "continuously" now? Did you write a loop? If so, you can exit that loop.

Comment: @Thilo it is called externally every time motion is detected. Anyway, what I need is to exits from the thread at the moment i call the method, not later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return from the first thread, once you are done detecting the movement.

Answer (score -2):

edit:

You should have a boolean variable inside a thread which will serve as a flag informing the thread if it should run or stop. If the flag is set to true the thread should run else the thread sholud stop and you should return from it.
If you want to finish the thread just set this variable to false.

Comment: The author asked which method/way to **use**, you wrote a reference to method **not to use**. Please consider improving the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer. The explanation in my previous post why this method should not be used contained also the correct method to do it, but now it is plain and simple.